# PreferenceScreen default settings during first run

Tags: android, null, crash, listpreference, preferencescreen

Good day,

I have a problem - I have a PreferenceScreen with a ListPreference that has default values. Then, I have an Activity that gets a value from that ListPreference, but it returns "null" if I do not open PreferenceScreen first.

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String prefSize = sp.getString("size", null);
    Size = Integer.parseInt(prefSize);
    mySize = Size;
```

Is it possible to do something about it? If I open my PreferenceScreen and then go to the activity it returns the default value, but if I open my Activity during the first run before I open the PreferenceScreen (just open, not changing any setttings) it the app crashes.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String prefSize = sp.getString("size", "1");//provide deafult values to parse into int for first time
Size = Integer.parseInt(prefSize);
mySize = Size;
```

Comment: Thank you! Solved the problem, but I wonder if there is a way to initialise the settings from the PreferenceScreen!